# Using grep to adjust timecode

Tags: sed, grep

I'm trying to change the timecode found from one format into another, basically to remove the milliseconds off the end of a file and update it. This is to remove extra milliseconds from a transcription timecode software and make it look pretty for file for client.

Input looks like this:

```
00:50:34.00>INTERVIEWER
Why was it ............... script?

00:50:35.13>JOHN DOE
Because of the quality.
```

So I'm trying to use grep to match the timecode and got it working with following expression.

```
grep [0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9] -P -o transcriptionFile.txt
```

Output looks like this:

```
00:50:34.00
00:50:35.13
```

So now I'm trying to take timecode and update the file with updated values like:

```
00:50:34
00:50:35
```

How do I do that? Should I use a pipe to push it over to sed so I can update the values in the file?

I've also tried to use sed with following command:

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]/g' transcriptionFile.txt > outtranscriptionFile.txt
```

I get output but puts in my RegExp in place where timecode is supposed to be. Any ideas? Also How do I can trim last 3 digits off far right side of timecode before I update file?

Any tips or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks :-)

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input. We can't tell for sure what you want to do by reading a script that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: As always, a lot depends on what else is in the file. Maybe `sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]>/>/g'` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\>\.[0-9]{2}/\1/' transcriptionFile.txt

00:50:34>INTERVIEWER
Why was it ............... script?

00:50:35>JOHN DOE
Because of the quality.
```

To edit the file *in place*, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -r -i 's/^([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\>\.[0-9]{2}/\1/' transcriptionFile.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `[0-9]{2}:` matches every two digits followed by a `:`. All three occurences are captured using brackets.
- `\>\.[0-9]{2}` matches `>` followed by a dot and two digits.
- using backreference `\1`, strings matching previous pattern are replaced with captured characters (timecode without milliseconds).

Comment: Changed from using Kali Linux to Ubuntu Linux and now script runs GNU sed style and is working :-)
Thanks for reduced syntax in [0-9]{2} syntax make more readable and using back reference also good tip.